# Powershell: Create PSCustomObject from Array

Tags: powershell, azure-active-directory

I have a PowerShell-Object `$foo` with 2 properties: `Column` and `Row`. Each Property contains an array of Items:

```
$foo.Column
{Cost, UsageDate, Currency}

$foo.Row
{120, 20230301, USD, 150, 20230302, USD, 200, 20230303, USD ... }
```

How do I get a PS-CustomObject `$bar` from it that looks like this

```
$bar | Format-Table

Cost     UsageDate     Currency
----     ---------     --------
120      20230301      USD
150      20230302      USD
200      20230302      USD
```

Comment: Is this from a csv?

Comment: Nope, from an Azure cmdlet ``Invoke-AzCostManagementQuery``

Comment: Eww.  Does running .tojson() on the IQueryResult output make it easier to deal with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks guys! I 've solved it this way:

Creating an empty Object first:

```
$temp = @()
```

Adding the Header to the Object

```
$temp = @()
$temp += $foo.columns.name -join ";"
```

Adding the rows to the Object:

```
$temp += $foo.rows -replace(" ",";")
```

And convert it:

```
$bar = $temp | ConvertFrom-Csv -Delimiter ";"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `for` loop to sequentially iterate between Rows and Columns and an [ordered dictionary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_hash_tables?view=powershell-7.2#creating-ordered-dictionaries) to create a new object. For example:

```bash
$foo = [pscustomobject]@{
    Column = 'Cost', 'UsageDate', 'Currency'
    Row    = '120', '20230301', 'USD'
}

$result = [ordered]@{}
for($i = 0; $i -lt $foo.Column.Length; $i++) {
    $result[$foo.Column[$i]] = $foo.Row[$i]
}
[pscustomobject] $result
```

If the object has more than one row then the logic needs to change:

```bash
$foo = [pscustomobject]@{
    Column = 'Cost', 'UsageDate', 'Currency'
    Row    = '120', '20230301', 'USD', '120', '20230301', 'USD'
}

$result = [ordered]@{}; $i = 0
foreach($row in $foo.Row) {
    $result[$foo.Column[$i++]] = $row
    if($i -eq $foo.Column.Length) {
        $i = 0
        [pscustomobject] $result
        $result.Clear()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Santiago. But I was not excact enough. ``$foo.Row`` can contain multiple values. I have updated my question.

Answer (score 1):

If this is what your `$foo` object looks like, you can do this like below

```
$foo = [PsCustomobject]@{
    Column = 'Cost', 'UsageDate', 'Currency'
    Row    = '120', '20230301', 'USD', '150', '20230302', 'USD', '200', '20230303', 'USD'  # etcetera
}
```

Then create the data as PsCustomObject:

```
$bar = for ($r = 0; $r -lt ($foo.Row.Count - 2); $r += 3) {
    $temp = [ordered]@{}
    for($i = 0; $i -lt $foo.Column.Count; $i++) {
        $temp[$foo.Column[$i]] = $foo.Row[$i + $r]
    }
    [PsCustomobject]$temp
}
# output on screen

$bar
```

or even

```
$header = ($foo.Column | ForEach-Object { '"{0}"' -f $_ }) -join ','
$data = for ($r = 0; $r -lt ($foo.Row.Count - 2); $r += 3) {
    ($r..($r + 2) | ForEach-Object { '"{0}"' -f $foo.Row[$_] }) -join ','
}

$bar = $header, $data | ConvertFrom-Csv
# output on screen
$bar
```

Output:

```
Cost UsageDate Currency
---- --------- --------
120  20230301  USD     
150  20230302  USD     
200  20230303  USD
```

Answer (score 0):

How about a one-liner that avoids incrementing indices?

Create a multiline string in `.csv` format and  pipe it to [`ConvertFrom-Csv`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertfrom-csv?view=powershell-7.3).

```
$bar = ($foo.Column -join ','), ( ($foo.Row -join ',') -replace '(?=\,\d+\,\d{8}\,[A-Z]{3})\,',"`n" ) -join "`n" | ConvertFrom-Csv
```

In action:

```
PS > $foo = [PsCustomobject]@{
>>     Column = 'Cost', 'UsageDate', 'Currency'
>>     Row    = '120', '20230301', 'USD', '150', '20230302', 'USD', '200', '20230303', 'USD'
>> }
PS >
PS > $bar = ($foo.Column -join ','), ( ($foo.Row -join ',') -replace '(?=\,\d+\,\d{8}\,[A-Z]{3})\,',"`n" ) -join "`n" | ConvertFrom-Csv
PS >                                                                                    PS > $bar

Cost UsageDate Currency
---- --------- --------
120  20230301  USD
150  20230302  USD
200  20230303  USD
```

The `-replace` operator's match expression uses a [posirive lookahead](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-quickstart.html#lookarounds)  to match only those commas that are followed by:

- `<digits>,<8 digits>,<3 letters>`

and replaces those with newline characters, creting the rows of the `.csv`.

So the only real brainwork is creating the regex that will match an entire row of data.